# Homeomorphism of a triangle.

Tags: general-topology

Let $\triangle$ be any equilateral triangle with its interior embedded in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Given that $f:\triangle\rightarrow\triangle$ is an homeomorphism. How can I prove that $f$ is an isometry?

I don't know how to begin this problem. I'll appreciate an advice.

Comment: You can't prove that $f$ is an isometry, because that doesn't follow from the given information.

Comment: Why not? Can you give me some reason to that, please?

Comment: A topology space with this property (i.e every homeomophism is an isometry) is known as topologically rigid. Do not get confuse with the term use in the Wikipedia.

Comment: Let the vertices of your triangle be A, B, and C; let P and Q be two distinct points in the interior of the triangle.  Define $f$ to (1) map each of $A,B,C$ to itself, (2) map $P$ to $Q$, and (3) be linear on each of the triangles $APB$, $BPC$, and $CPA$.  that's a homeomorphism but not an isometry.

Comment: Another example: Circumscribe a circle around your triangle, and let $D$ be that circle together with its interior.  Let $p$ be the homeomorphism from your triangle to $D$ given by radial projection (linear on each radius), and let $r$ be a rotation of $D$ around its center.  then $p^{-1}\circ r\circ p$ is a homeomorphism.  It's an isometry only when the rotation $r$ is by a multiple of 120 degrees.

Comment: "In your comment about "topologically rigid", you presumably meant "metric space" rather than "topology space", because the notion of "isometry" is defined only in the presence of a metric.

Comment: Very interesting. Thanks for being so illustrative. Can you post your counterexamples as answer? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Andreas points out, it's not true.

Select a closed disk $\overline{B}(x, r)$ contained in the triangle. Then every point in the disk is of the form $x + \alpha v$ for some $\alpha \in [0, 1]$ and $v \in \mathbb{R}^2$ with $|v| = 1$. Put $f : \overline{B}(x, r) \to \overline{B}(x, r)$ as $f( x + \alpha v ) = x + \alpha^2 v$ and an identity map elsewhere. $f$ is a homeomorphism but not an isometry.

Comment: I don't understand your example. How the function $f$ is defined over all the triangle?

Comment: @YotasTrejos: As said: by the formula on the disk and by identity elseware.